# Excel Conditional Formatting reference cell until data is Manually Entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet, that has a sheet for predicted data and another for manually entered data. the sheets look identical.

I would like so that the prediction shows on the Manual sheet, but in light grey (conditional formatting). however once the actual data is entered manually into the that cell, i want it to see that is the live data and remove the conditional formatting, as well as allow other formulas to see that it is now live data and use that to do what it normally does.

Previously I've used the isblank function so that if the say A1 or A2 fields are blank then to stay blank, and if several other cells see that A1 or A2 are blank then not to show anything either, i want this still to happen but for A1 and A2 to show the data that has been predicted on the prediction sheet.

I hope I've managed to explain that well enough. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Excel 2016 if that helps

Comment: you might be able to use the function ISFORMULA, rather than ISBLANK

Comment: @PeterH Doh!!! so unbelievably simple. cheers for that, never knew about isformula, just tried it and it worked perfectly. Thank you! should i leave this question open or delete it?

Comment: I would leave it open, may help someone else in the future, UPVOTED to get you going on SU aswell

Answer (score 1):

If the prediction is being generated with a formula, it should be simple enough to select the table and choose 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format', and into the box enter `=isformula(ref)`. Replace the `ref` with the cell name in the top-left corner after you have selected it all.

Answer (score 0):

select column A. Home > conditionalFormatting > Manage Rule > New Rule > RuleType : Use Formula. Put in :

`=isformula(A1)`

Then set the light grey fill "Format"... > OK.

Hope that solves. (: